# Converting subscript in fortranform

Tags: format, fortran

i have a matrix like this:

```
F := Table[Subscript[f, i, j], {i, 3}, {j, 3}]
c=F.F
```

my question is that how to convert the components of c to this form Subscript[f, i, j]->f(i,j) when i am using FortranForm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what do you expect from `Lists` but here is a quick solution:

```
FortranForm[c /. Subscript -> (#[##2] &)]
```

[image]

*Edit:*

> dear Kuba i am looking for something like this : c(1,1)=f(1,1)^2+f(1,2)*f(2,1)+f(1,3)*f(3,1) and so on. –

```
Column @ Flatten @ MapIndexed[
  StringTemplate["c(``,``) = ``", InsertionFunction -> ToString
  ][
    Sequence @@ #2, FortranForm[# /. Subscript -> (#[##2] &)]
  ] &
, c
, {2}
]
```

[image]

Comment: dear Kuba i am looking for something like this : c(1,1)=f(1,1)^2+f(1,2)*f(2,1)+f(1,3)*f(3,1) and so on.

Comment: @user49047 please see the edit.